# Add sub-property of property to PSObject in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm using PowerShell to get JSON content that is returned back as a PSObject so that when I want to call a property's value in the object, I can get the value by calling the variable like:

```
$endpoint.authorization
```

But I would like to add a new property inside of the existing authorization property to end up looking like:

```
$endpoint.authorization.parameters.username
```

I have figured out that I can pipe the variable with the Select and Add-Member cmdlets but it doesn't look like it does anything when I call the original variable again. Here's what my code looks like:

```
$endpoint | Select -Property "authorization" | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "parameters.username" -NotePropertyValue "test"
```

And nothing seems to change in the endpoint variable when I check it after that line of code. There must be something simple that I'm missing, but any ideas on how I can add a new property as a sub-property of an existing one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select is building a new [PSCustomObject] with just the property you specified, you add properties to it, then you throw it away.

Referencing a property returns a value, so you need to add something to the authorization property, then add something to that:

```
$endpoint = "{'authorization':{}}" | ConvertFrom-Json
$endpoint.authorization | Add-Member -NotePropertyName parameters -NotePropertyValue ([PSCustomObject]@{})
$endpoint.authorization.parameters | Add-Member -NotePropertyName username -NotePropertyValue test

PS D:\> $endpoint

authorization                                                                                                    
-------------                                                                                                    
@{parameters=}                                                                                                   



PS D:\> $endpoint.authorization

parameters                                                                                                       
----------                                                                                                       
@{username=test}                                                                                                 



PS D:\> $endpoint.authorization.parameters

username                                                                                                         
--------                                                                                                         
test                                                                                                             



PS D:\> $endpoint.authorization.parameters.username
test

PS D:\>
```

Or you could do it in one go by building up the thing you want to add, then adding it, e.g.

```
$endpoint = "{'authorization':{}}" | ConvertFrom-Json
$endpoint.authorization | Add-Member -NotePropertyName parameters -NotePropertyValue ([PSCustomObject]@{'username'='test'})
```

---

**Help Links** (if available):

- ConvertFrom-Json is [`ConvertFrom-Json`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=217031) (in module Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility)
- Add-Member is [`Add-Member`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113280) (in module Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility)

Comment: This is awesome, TessellatingHeckler!!